# Why is onmousedown triggered when the mouse is clicked elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with an onmousedown event, but it is triggering when I click far outside of the div.
This screenshot shows where I had just clicked and registered a mousedown on the square.  I think I have it obsessively annotated enough to be helpful... though I accidentally wrote "Picker" instead of "Switcher"... I have confirmed that "Picker" is no where in my code.

If you look on [the page, active on my server](http://www.readyrental.ca/colourSwitcher.html) you can duplicate this yourself.  It doesn't happen all the time, but OFTEN.  The div on the right fills with one letter per event that is triggered and not cancelled for one reason or another, which I used to diagnose the problem.

I'm a new user (sory - new in general, so haven't answered or asked anything) so can't post images.
**Edit:** Here's the image:

[image]

```
#colourSwitcherMapBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
}
#colourSwitcherMapMark {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: -8px;
  left: 248px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
}
#colourSwitcherMapBox div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

<div id="colourSwitcherContainer" class="colourSwitcherStuff" onmousedown="colourSwitcherDrag(event);">
  Colour Switcher:<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleColourSwitcher(this.checked);" />
  <div id="mainColourSwitcher">
    <div id="colourSwitcherMapBox" onmousedown="colourSwitcherDragMap(event);">
      <div id="colourSwitcherMapMark"><img src="imagesCP/mapIndicator.png" alt="" /></div>
      <div id="colourSwitcherMaxB"><img src="imagesCP/map-blue-max.png" alt="" /></div>
      ... lots more divs identical to the last line other than image and  ...
    </div>
   ... other stuff (colourSwitcherBarBox and colourSwitcherPickInfo) ...
  </div>
</div>

function colourSwitcherDragMap (event) {
  if (!event) {var event = window.event;}
  if (event.preventDefault) {event.preventDefault();} else { event.returnValue = false; }
  document.body.onmousemove = colourSwitcherChangeBar;
  document.body.onmouseup = colourSwitcherStopDragging;
  document.getElementById("randomblob").innerHTML += "M ";
  colourSwitcherChangeBar (event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colourSwitcherMapMark` accidentally picks up a height and width of 256px from this rule:

```
#colourSwitcherMapBox div {
    height: 256px;
    ...
```

making it much bigger than it needs to be. So if the marker is nearer the bottom of the colour area, it will hang over the edge of the colourSwitcherContainer and pick up clicks. I don't think you intended this rule to match the MapMark; you will have to make it more specific, to only pick up the main div you want it to.

Comment: Thanks!!  After manually checking 450 lines of Javascript it was CSS priority.  FIXED!

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of that "colourSwitcherMapMark" `<div>`, which is lexically inside the other `<div>` ("colourSwitcherMatchBox") but absolutely-positioned outside of it. Events bubble up the DOM based on lexical relationships between elements, not screen position. Thus, when you click there, even though *that* `<div>` has no event handler, the browser shops it up the DOM tree to see if any parent elements want it.

You can check the "target" property of the event object in your handler to make sure the click happened where you want it to happen, but to me the position of that other `<div>` doesn't make a lot of sense anyway.

Using something like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools, the "HTML" or "Elements" views can show you what elements are where on the page.

Comment: In this case I specifically want events to bubble up through that small circular div, but thanks!

Comment: Well OK, that's fine, but that's definitely what's happening. That area to the "south" of the thin color "zone" bar is where that "MapMark" element is positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the click from "bubbling" up the dom by using event.stopPropagation().  IE handles events differently than everyone else, so you need to code to handle both.  Here's some code from my toolkit -- it's 2 years old, but I still use it and haven't had any problems.

```
function myclick(e){
    if(e && e.stopPropagation) { 
        // Everyone but IE
        e.stopPropagation();
    } 
    else {  
        // IE
        e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit** - This is a good last resort, but as Matt states in the comments, you should examine closely the design of your app to see if there's a better way to structure your divs so that you don't have to muck with the event-handling internals of the browser.

Comment: Killing events can be both expensive and dangerous when factoring in event dependencies between nodes.

Comment: @Matt - Agreed, but in the context of the program the user has posted, it seems like it would be ok.  I'll caveat my answer with your input.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the click outside hits the event handler, then that area is part of the element on which you have the event handler hooked.

You have these event handlers on div. The other areas which seems clear, but they are inside the divs.

You should be able to see which area they cover using FireBug e.g.

The solution is to limit the div by specific width and height.

Comment: They are already limited in the CSS... incorrectly.  thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Your `#colourSwitcherMapMark` selector is not strong enough, so the div is actually 256x256 instead of 15x15.  Change it to `div#colourSwitcherMapMark`.

Comment: Thanks!  I made it #colourSwitcherMapBox #colourSwitcherMapMark to be very strong and very specific.